# Fortify scan using maven sca plugin

Tags: fortify

I am trying to use maven-sca-plugin  to scan  java app.  It looks like by default it scans only java code, How can i make the plugin include  jsp and other file types for translate phase.

Thanks
Rv

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can scan some JSP but it needs to be in a set location by default and in a standard tree structure. To verify or modify the plugin, the source is included with newer versions of SCA, located at

```
<SCA install>/Samples/advanced/maven-plugin/
```